# Getting $B$ from $A = M^t B M$ without inverting $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, inverse

I have got three matrices: $A$ (dimension $n \times n$), $B$ (dimension $m \times m$) and $M$ (dimension $m \times n$). We have $m > n$.

This is the relation between these three matrices: $A = M^t B M$

$M$ is lower triangular, $B$ is symmetric.

Is there a way to get the unknown matrix $B$ from the known matrices $A$ and $M$, without explicitly inverting $M$ or $M^t$? What I mean is that I cannot write $B = (M^t)^{-1} A M^{-1}$, I would rather need a sort of backsubstitution method, with an explicit formula for a generic element $B_{i j}$ of $B$.

The way I started thinking about this is that one could start by noticing, after some algebra, that

$B_{m m} = \frac{A_{n n}}{M^t_{nm} M_{m n}} = \frac{A_{n n}}{M_{m n}^2}$

but then I am not able to provide a generic formula for $B_{i j}$.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by inverting? I mean, as $M$ is a $m \times n$-matrix with $m > n$ it is clearly not invertible. Also, given $M$ and $A$, the matrix $B$ is clearly not unique, as any $n \times n$-matrix $C$ with $M^t C M = 0$ gives another solution $B + C$. Or do you want to find all solutions?

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear. If $m$ where exactly the same as $n$ then we would have squared matrices and we could use the inversion to get $B$ from $A$. Instead, in the case $m \neq n$, I would ilke to find a method to extrapolate every single entry of $B$ from those of $A$ and $M$

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: I've expanded the main points of your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Matthias Klubsch pointed out: If $M$ is not square, we cannot find $B$ in a unique way.

Let's split up $M$ and $B$ into blocks: As $M$ is $m \times n$ and lower triangular, we can split it into a lower $n \times n$ block $M_2$ which is lower triangular and an upper $(m-n)\times n$ block which consists entirely of zeros. We split $B$ into blocks of according size:

$$B= \begin{pmatrix}B_{11} & B_{12} \\B_{21} & B_{22}\end{pmatrix}, \  M=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ M_2 \end{pmatrix},$$

where $B_{11}$ is $(m-n)\times(m-n) $, $B_{12}$ is $n\times(m-n) $, $B_{21}$ is $(n-m)\times n $ and $B_{22}$ is $n\times n$, see the edit below for the definition of the blocks.

Now we can multiply:

$$A=M^tBM = \begin{pmatrix}0 & M_2^t \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}B_{11} & B_{12} \\B_{21} & B_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ M_2 \end{pmatrix} = M_2^t B_{22}M_2.$$

This means that the equation $A=M^tBM$ does not contain *any* information to determine the parts of $B$ which are not in the lower right $n\times n$ corner.

Addtionally, if the square matrix $M_2$ is not of full rank (i.e. has zeros on the diagonal) then we can't even get unique values for $B_{22}$, since with any solution of $M_2^tC_{22}M_2=0$ we would also get a solution $B_{22} + C_{22}$ of $$A= M^t B M = M_2^t (B_{22}+ C_{22})M_2$$

**Edit:** This splitting is done by defining

$(B_{11})_{ij} = (B)_{ij},\  i,j= 1,\dots m-n$

$(B_{12})_{ij} = (B)_{ij}, \ i= m-n + 1, \dots, m ,\ j= 1,\dots m-n $

$(B_{21})_{ij} = (B)_{ij}, \ j= 1,\dots m-n, \ i= m-n + 1, \dots, m \ , $

$(B_{22})_{ij} = (B)_{ij}, i,j= m-n + 1, \dots, m $

$(M_2)_{ij}= (M)_{ij}, \ i= m-n +1 , \dots, m, \ j=1,\dots, n$

**Edit 2:** Suppose that $M$ has a different shape than outlined above, namely the upper square matrix $(M)_{ij}, \ i,j =1, \dots, n$ is lower triangular and the residual lower block is not of any particular shape. By the comments, this is what OP meant with lower triangular.  (I'd call this lower trapeziodal. But this is semantics.)

We can find a $QR-$decomposition for $M$ such that

$$M = Q R = Q \begin{pmatrix} R_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},$$

where $Q$ is an $m \times m$ orthogonal matrix, $R$ is an $m \times n$ *upper* triangular matrix and its upper square block $R_1$ is an $n \times n$ upper triangular matrix.

Instead of $A= M^t B M$, we write

$$A = (QR)^t B (QR) = \begin{pmatrix} R_1^t & 0 \end{pmatrix} Q^t B Q \begin{pmatrix} R_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

We define $B' = Q^t B Q$ (since $Q$ is orthogonal, the task of finding $B$ is equivalent to finding $B'$ and calculating $B = Q B' Q^t$) and split $B'$ into square blocks and find, as above:

$$A = R_1^t B'_{11} R_1,$$

where $(B_{11}')_{ij} = (Q^t B Q)_{ij}, \ i,j, = 1, \dots,n$

Again, with this information, and supposing that $R_1$ has full rank, we can only uniquely determine $B_{11}'$, but not any of the other blocks of $B'$. Thus, we cannot determine $B$ uniquely.

Comment: How can I split $M$ into a lower block diagonal matrix and an upper block of zeros? And by the way $M$ is lower triangular, not upper

Comment: @johnhenry I wrote down the definitions of the block matrices. Note that $M_2$ is not only lower triangular, but in contrast to $M$, also square. Fixed the typo.

Comment: thank you for your clarification, but are you sure about the definition of $M_2$? I am sorry if I am insisting on it, but by cutting out the rows of $M$ before $m-n+1$, are you not getting rid of elements in $M$ that are NOT zeros? thank you again

Comment: @johnhenry: Thanks for your question. Maybe we have a different unterstanding of $M$ being lower triangular: As far as I understand it, the matrix 'M' is a 'tall' matrix and there is a triangle sitting on the bottom of $M$ such that everything above this triangle is equal to zero. Is this what you mean by $M$ being lower triangular? If not, do you mind to write down which elements of $M$ are zero and which aren't neccesarily zero?

Comment: You are definitely right when you say that $M$ is a "tall" matrix. Regarding its elements: all the elements underneath the diagonal are non-zero. The diagonal elements are non-zero, too. All the elements above the diagonal are zero.

Comment: @johnhenry Thanks for clarifying. I see where our misunderstanding came from. I've edited my answer to cover this case as well.